# Use both WCF service and Web Api in same Service fabric reliable services

Tags: wcf, azure, asp.net-web-api, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I haven't had much luck finding a way of using the WCFCommunicationListener as well as HttpListner(OwinCommunicationListner) inside same Reliable service. I Want to use two different listeners one that provide the Soap functionality that I can achieve using WCFCommunicationListener and other will simple Web Api consumption that what pretty much OwinCommunicationListner provides. I don't want to use the WcfCommunicationListener for my REST functionalities, I want to consume my REST apis as Web Api.

Comment: Why not use two distinct services to achieve this? One for the web api accessible by http and one for the soap / wcf call?

Comment: @PeterBons achieved that using two distinct services. Thanks, for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I will run two of them on two separated services. Using Docker for WCF and Owin for Web API. 
If the problem you have is trying to share code then just have a shared library outside of the two services.

An sample on WCF on Docker here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/20/lets-try-wcf-self-hosted-services-in-a-container/